# Store tree structured data to an array in C without declaring the array outside of the function

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, tree

I am trying to write a code to transverse tree-structured data using inorder transversal and store all the tree nodes onto an array.

```
void inorderTraversal(AVLTreeNode *node, AVLTreeNode *nodesArray[], int *index)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    inorderTraversal(node->left, nodesArray, index);
    nodesArray[*index] = node;
    (*index)++;
    inorderTraversal(node->right, nodesArray, index);
}
```

It works if I declare the `index` first in the main function as below

```
int index = 0;

inorderTraversal(tree->root, nodesArray, &index);
```

But it wouldn't work if I simply do this below.

```
inorderTraversal(tree->root, nodesArray, &0);
```

How could I just use `0` pass onto the function without declaring it in the main function firstly?

Comment: If you don't use a variable, where are you going to store the `index`?

Comment: Is there a way to include the variable inside the `inorderTraversal` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&0` doesn't make sense because the `&` operator is used to get the address of an object.  Integer literals aren't objects and therefore don't have an address.

If you don't plan on using the value of `index` after the function completes, you can pass the address of a *compound literal*:

```
inorderTraversal(tree->root, nodesArray, &(int){0});
```

This creates a temporary object whose address can be taken and ceases to exist after the statement in which it is used.

Still, I'd argue that you *want* to keep this value so you know how many values are in `nodesArray` after `inorderTraversal` completes.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I want, to create a temporary object, and it doesn't take any more memory space once the function completes. But I like your suggestion to keep the value for a quick sanity check! Thank you

Comment: May I also ask if passing a temporary object onto function good practice in coding C?